# Serilog is not creating log SQL table when I run the application in .NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

I have the appsettings.json setup to create the log table automatically with `"autoCreateSqlTable": true`

However, I checked SQL but the table is nowhere to be found. I can't seem to find what is causing it to not create and log the information.

Program.cs :

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            .CreateLogger();

        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>().UseSerilog();
            });
}
```

appsettings.json:

```
"Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "****",
          "tableName": "Log",
          "autoCreateSqlTable": true
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My Project is based on **.Net5.0** Core MVC and project has below nuget packages installed.

```
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" Version="5.6.0" />
```

Below config and program.cs file works for me.

> Make sure your Serilog in appsettings.json has this line "Using":["Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer"] as shown below:

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "Override": {
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "Error",
      "Microsoft": "Error",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "Warnning"
    },
    "WriteTo": [         
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "Server=dbserverhost.domain.com;Database=DBName; Trusted_Connection=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
          "schemaName": "dbo",
          "tableName": "AppLogs",
          "autoCreateSqlTable": true
          //,
          //"columnOptionsSection": {
          //  "removeStandardColumns": [ "Properties" ]
          //  //,
          //  //"customColumns": [
          //  //  {
          //  //    "ColumnName": "EventType",
          //  //    "DataType": "int",
          //  //    "AllowNull": false
          //  //  },
          //  //  {
          //  //    "ColumnName": "Release",
          //  //    "DataType": "varchar",
          //  //    "DataLength": 32
          //  //  }
          //  //]
          //}
        }
        ,
        "restrictedToMinimumLevel":  "Warning"
      }
    ]
  }
```

> My Program.cs file

```
using Serilog;
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .Build();


            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
                //.WriteTo.File("Logs/log-.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
                .CreateLogger();
            
            Log.Information("Hello {Name} from thread {ThreadId}", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME"), Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            

            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                var loggerFactory = services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
            }

            host.Run();

            // CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

> Serilog Default Create Table, For more details click [here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver#table-definition)

```
CREATE TABLE [Logs] (

   [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [Message] nvarchar(max) NULL,
   [MessageTemplate] nvarchar(max) NULL,
   [Level] nvarchar(128) NULL,
   [TimeStamp] datetime NOT NULL,
   [Exception] nvarchar(max) NULL,
   [Properties] nvarchar(max) NULL

   CONSTRAINT [PK_Logs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC) 
);
```

Comment: Hi - I added the 'using' and the table still hasn't appeared in my database, mine pretty much looks like yours.

Comment: Have you check user permission on SQL DB normally it should work but if you have restricted DB access ,make sure your user should have db_owner or db_ddladmin at least to work.

Comment: Add this line in your code Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Console.WriteLine(msg)); this will show you if it is permission issue from DB side

Comment: I got the following error: Unable to write 19 log events to the database due to following error: Login failed for user 'ffsqladm'. The connection string is correct it is the same one I use to read and write to.

Comment: To create a new table it does required higher privileges. Serilog is going to create a new table so make sure, the user is having create table permission on the db. Normally db_ddlowner or db_owner will do the work. Simple test by using same user create a test table and see. If you are able to create a table using same user means Serilog should be able to create 'Log' table.

Comment: https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/raw-tech/How-To-Fix-Login-Failed-for-User-Microsoft-SQL-Server-Error-18456-Step-By-Step

Answer (score 3):

Creating tables in SQL Server requires certain permissions that your user might not have and the sink might be unable to create the table due to permission error.

There are also other reasons that might be preventing the sink from even connecting to the database, such as a typo on the connection string, or incorrect user/password, etc.

Serilog sinks for logging are safe by default, and don't throw exceptions, so if you want to troubleshoot what's happening, you should look at [Serilog's SelfLog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics)

e.g.

```
Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Console.WriteLine(msg));
```

This will print any errors from sinks in the Console (change to something else if you don't have a console app)

Comment: I got the following error: Unable to write 19 log events to the database due to following error: Login failed for user 'ffsqladm', The connection string is correct it is the same one I use to read and write to.

Comment: Perhaps the connection string is not being correctly read from the config file? Have you tried using the same connection string configuring the SQL Server Sink via C#?

Comment: I don't see anything in the Console relating to Serilog errors. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a little catch for auto creating the table as there are two distinct properties in SqlServerSinkOptions: AutoCreateSqlDatabase and AutoCreateSqlTable.
For me, it only created the table when both of them were set to true:

```
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(
            connectionString: builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("LogsDbConnection"),
            sinkOptions: new MSSqlServerSinkOptions
            {
                AutoCreateSqlDatabase = true,
                AutoCreateSqlTable = true,
                TableName = "Logs",
            }
        )
        .CreateLogger();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that you have `database` and `schema` created. In my case, when using `Serilog.sinks.postgresql`, database and schema would not be created automatically.

Answer (score 0):

use script in https://gist.github.com/mivano/10429656 or set `AutoCreateSqlTable=True`

```
.WriteTo.MSSqlServer(
            connectionString: connectionString,
            sinkOptions: new Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer.MSSqlServerSinkOptions() { 
                TableName = "Logs", 
                SchemaName="dbo", 
                AutoCreateSqlTable=true 
            }
)
```

Comment: This don't actually create the table automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully added Serilog SQL SERVER logging by following [this](https://www.carlrippon.com/asp-net-core-logging-with-serilog-and-sql-server/) short, helpful tutorial. Hope it helps others.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Please don't only refer to a link with the solution, but extract the information from the source link and add it into the answer. Please read this before posting an answer next time: [How To: Write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34960006)